# error couldn't find the 'fopn_foweb' security handler

Tags: errors, pdf, drm

I use LaTex to compile .pdf files together, but I have the types of files that requires "[Fileopen](http://www.fileopen.com/) adobe plug-in" to be installed to open them. I have installed the plug-in and am able to open them using adobe reader. But they are still protected of course. I run my latex to compile them and get this error : `Syntax error: couldn't find 'FOPN_foweb' security handler`. I don't usually get this error with other protected pdf files.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*\FICHIERPDF[1]{\IfFileExists{FICHIERPDF/"#1.pdf"}{\pdfbookmark[3]{#1}{#1}\includepdf[pages={-},fitpaper=true]{FICHIERPDF/#1}\cleardoublepage}{\relax}}


\begin{document}

\FICHIERPDF{1413} %1413.pdf is the document trying to be included for example.
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileOpen](http://www.fileopen.com/) is some kind of [drm](/questions/tagged/drm) which is not supported by any free software. Including these files *with* DRM will not work.